# XSLT transformation XML to HTML to generate navigation section and internal links

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to do an XML to HTML transformation using XSLT which generates (1) a separate contents list of the sections which links to the respective section; and (2) internal links to the relevant sections based on numbered references appearing throughout the file.

This is a fragment of the XML file in simplified form:

```
<content>
    <section>
        <num value="35">35. First title</num>
        <line>Text goes here.</line>
    </section>
    <section>
        <num value="36">36. Second title</num>
        <line>More text <ref>35</ref> here.</line>
    </section>
</content>
```

This is the desired HTML:

```
<body>
    <toc>
        <tocitem><a href="#35">35. First title.</a></tocitem>
        <tocitem><a href="#36">36. Second title.</a></tocitem>
    </toc>
    <content>
        <section>
            <num><a id="35">35. First title.</a></num>
            <p>Text goes here.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <num><a id="36">36. Second title</a></num>
            <p>More text <ref><a href="#35">35</a></ref> here.</p>
        </section>
    </content>
</body>
```

This is the XSLT I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <toc>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="num" mode="links"/>
            </toc>
            <content>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </content>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="num" mode="toc">
    <tocitem>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </tocitem>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used an identity transform and then tried to process the num elements again using mode. However the toc is empty. For the links I have tried using id/href and generate-id but not got very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="num" mode="links"/>
```

doesn't do anything because:

1. `num` is not a child of the context node (which is the root node); and
2. There is no template matching `num` in mode `links`.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="content/section/num" mode="toc"/>
```

And you probably want to modify the matching template so that it also produces the `a` element:

```
<xsl:template match="num" mode="toc">
    <tocitem>
        <a href="#{@value}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </tocitem>
</xsl:template>
```

And also add a template matching `line` to transform it into `p`.